# Having a small Issue running a Perl scripts IF statement.

Tags: linux, perl

I created a small script in Perl and I am really new to this. I'm supposed to have a script that looks at an argument given and create a directory tree in the given argument. This part of the script works. The second part (which is the nested if statement) does not when you do not give an argument and it asks you to input a directory of your choice. I believe the nested if statement is messing up due to the $file input but I'm not entirely sure whats wrong. This is probably something really simple, but I have not been able to find the solution. Thank you in advance for the help and tips.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

if ($#ARGV == -1) 
 {
   print "Please enter default directory:";
   my $file=<STDIN>;

   if (-d $file)
    {   
      chdir $file;
      system("mkdir Data");
      system("mkdir Data/Image"); 
      system("mkdir Data/Cache");
      print "Structure Created";
    }
   else
    {
      print "Directory does not exsist";
    }  
 }
else
 {
   chdir $ARGV[0];
   system("mkdir Data");
   system("mkdir Data/Image"); 
   system("mkdir Data/Cache");
   print ("Structure Created");
 }
print ("\n");
```

Comment: Need `chomp($file)` after you read it in.  What is typed in via `STDIN` comes with the newline, and `-d $file` doesn't find `filename\n` (since it is really `filename`).  Also, why test for `-1` for the index of the last element of `@ARGV` (which is what `$#ARGV` is)?  If you are testing whether  `@ARGV` array is empty you can say `if (not @ARGV)`

Comment: Using a `$file` variable to hold a directory name is probably confusing yourself more than it confuses us. Get the arg out first near the top of the script: `if (! @ARGV){ die "no args supplied...\n"; }; $my dir = $ARGV[0];`. The `<STDIN>` will take whatever you send in on the command line, while the program is running, and that's different from the command line args (`ARGV`). (@zdim showed in comments how to strip the newline). There are several optimizations that can be had as well, but there's not enough information to yet formulate a full answer.

Comment: @stevieb  I think they mean to offer `STDIN` input if nothing was submitted on the command line.  If that is the case then they can't `die` when `@ARGV` is empty. I agree that it is a little unclear.

Comment: @zdim yeah, that makes some sense. There's an answer to be given here particularly that utilizes some built-ins, but I digress... I'm unclear as to what the real objective is. x/y it may be.

Comment: Hey guys thanks for the comments. I did what @zdim said and added the chomp($file); to the code and it works like a charm. Sorry for being that clear about the question. First time actually posting.

Comment: @Stapes  Thanks for the response -- it's a good question. As it turns out, writing them so to be crystal-clear isn't simple at all. I posted an answer, because of a few other things that I thought should be discussed.  Let me know if explanations are unclear or missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The test `-d $file` is failing because what is entered via `STDIN` also has the newline, after the string that specifies the directory name.  You need `chomp($file);`

---

However, there are a few more points I would like to bring up.

Most importantly, there is repeated code in both branches. You really do not want to do that. It can, and does, cause trouble later. Instead, decide on the directory name, and then make it.

Second, there is no reason to go out to the system in order to make a directory. It is far better to do it in Perl, and there are good modules for this.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Path qw(make_path);

my $dir;    
if (not @ARGV) {
    print "Please enter default directory: ";
    $dir = <STDIN>;
    chomp $dir;
}
else {
    $dir = $ARGV[0];
}   
die "No directory $dir"  if not -d $dir;

my $orig_cwd = chdir $dir or die "Can't chdir to $dir: $!";

my @dirs = map { "Data/$_" } qw(Image Cache);

my @dirs_made = make_path( @dirs, { verbose => 1 } );

print "Created directories:\n";
print "$_\n" for @dirs_made;
```

I build the directory list using [map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) so to avoid repeated strings with `Data/...`, and for later flexibility. You can of course just type the names in, but that tends to invite silly mistakes.

I used [File::Path](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Path.html) to make the directories.  It builds the whole path, like `mkdir -p`, and has a few other useful options that you can pass in `{ }`, including error handling.  There are other modules as well, for example [Path::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/~dagolden/Path-Tiny-0.100/lib/Path/Tiny.pm) with its `mkpath` (and a lot of other goodies).

Note that with [chdir](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chdir.html) you probably want to record the current working directory, that it returns, and that you want to check for error.  But you don't have to `chdir`, if there are no other reasons for that.  Just include the `$dir` name in the `map`

```
# No chdir needed here
my @dirs = map { "$dir/Data/$_" } qw(Image Cache);
```